# Save SwiftUI List selection using @AppStorage in a Mac app

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

In a Mac app, I'm trying to store a SwiftUI List selection using AppStorage. The goal is to have the app remember the last selection such that it is selected when the app restarts. I can't figure out how to bind the selection to the AppStorage property. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

```
enum Fruit: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case apple
    case orange
    case mango
    case lemon
    var id: String { rawValue }
}

struct Sidebar: View {

    @Binding var selection: Fruit

    var body: some View {
        List(Fruit.allCases, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { fruit in
            Text(fruit.rawValue)
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        .frame(minWidth: 150)
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {

    var selection: Fruit

    var body: some View {
        switch selection {
        case .apple:
            Text(" \(selection.rawValue)").font(.title).frame(minWidth: 200)
        case .orange:
            Text(" \(selection.rawValue)").font(.title).frame(minWidth: 200)
        case .mango:
            Text(" \(selection.rawValue)").font(.title).frame(minWidth: 200)
        case .lemon:
            Text(" \(selection.rawValue)").font(.title).frame(minWidth: 200)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("selection") private var selection: Fruit = .apple

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Sidebar(selection: $selection)
            DetailView(selection: selection)
        }
        .frame(width: 500, height: 300)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try onTapGesture selection = fruit in the side bar view . I am pretty sure you can’t use the List selection like you use a picker selection.

Comment: You can put an optional selection in a `List`. See [List](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list). However, the list is not taking the straight `@AppStorage` as a direct binding. You way is the simple work around to that issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom binding in selection.

```
struct Sidebar: View {
    
    @Binding var selection: Fruit

    var body: some View {
        List(Fruit.allCases, id: \.self, selection: Binding($selection)) { fruit in
            Text(fruit.rawValue)
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        .frame(minWidth: 150)
    }
}
```

or

```
List(Fruit.allCases, id: \.self, selection: Binding(get: {selection}, set: {selection = $0 ?? Fruit.apple}$selection)) {
```

Comment: Why not use `Binding($selection)`?

Comment: @wigging Yeah. It's an alternative. But you got the idea right?

Comment: Can you add to your answer the `Binding($selection)` approach? Just so others will be aware of it.

Comment: I meant that you show both approaches in your answer. That way people are aware of both ways to fix the problem. So please also show your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your `Binding`. You simply need a way of selecting the different fruits:

```
    List(Fruit.allCases, id: \.self) { fruit in
        Text(fruit.rawValue)
            .onTapGesture {
                selection = fruit
            }
    }
```

Otherwise, it works fine with what you have coded.

I am not sure how you are not getting this to work, but here is a video:
[Screen Recording 2021-10-04 at 11.10.29 AM(720)](https://app.box.com/s/x08locsgg6smercozkotdd8d0p1t3p40)

Comment: This does not work. It removes the `$selection` binding from the List so the selected item doesn't update.

Comment: It was tested on Xcode 13RC and MacOS 11.6.

Comment: I used Xcode 13 on macOS 11.6 too but the List selection does not work. If there is no `List(selection:)` then how do you update the List state? In your example, `selection` updates the binding for the view, not for the List.

Comment: Updated with video showing it is working.

Comment: In your video the sidebar items are not highlighted when you select an item because the selection state of the List is not updated. Here's an image of a working example https://pasteboard.co/pJsuXvA8Sgop.png

Comment: Got it. That is not what you have said above. While that is possible with my approach, my rule is to stick with Apple's implemented behavior as much as possible. Keeps things from breaking in the future.